# Can Anyone Explain Laravel 5.2 Multi Auth with Example

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-authorization

I am trying to authenticate **users** and **admin** form `user` table and `admin` table respectively. I am using the `User` model as provided by Laravel out of the box and created the same for `Admin.` I have added a guard key and provider key into `auth.php.`

**Guards**

```php
'guards' => [
    'user' =>[
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'user',
    ],
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admin',
    ],
],
```

**Providers**

```php
'providers' => [
    'user' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ]
],
```

**Routes**

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    // Login Routes.   
    Route::get('/admin/login','AdminAuth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
    Route::post('/admin/login','AdminAuth\AuthController@login');
    Route::get('/admin/logout','AdminAuth\AuthController@logout');

    // Registration Routes.
    Route::get('admin/register', 'AdminAuth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm');
    Route::post('admin/register', 'AdminAuth\AuthController@register');

    Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index');
});
```

I have created a directory called `AuthAdmin` where Laravel's default `AuthController.php` and `PasswordController.php` files are present. (Namespace Modified accordingly)

First of all, Laravel's docs mentioned how to specify a custom guard while authenticating like this which isn't working.
[image]

There's another method mentioned in Laravel's docs to use a guard which is not working too.

[image]

It would be beneficial if someone could resolve the issues and correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Laravel fixed a bug in version 5.2.6. `protected $guard = 'guard_name'` can be used now.

Comment: In Laravel there are many Admin panel generator packages available. I prefer Voyager Admin. Installing them easy and breeze. It may save you ton of code.
You just need to understand how it works. Don't reinvent the wheel. [Voyager - The Missing Laravel Admin](https://laravelvoyager.com/) [A Laravel application with Gentelella bootstrap admin tempalte.](https://github.com/FlorientR/laravel-gentelella)

Answer (score 204, accepted):

After lots of digging and lots of questions & answers I have finally managed to work Laravel 5.2 Multi Auth with two table, So I'm writing Answer of my own Question.

**How to implement Multi Auth in Laravel 5.2**

As Mentioned above.
Two table `admin` and `users`

Laravel 5.2 has a new `artisan` command.

`php artisan make:auth`

it will generate basic login/register `route`, `view` and `controller` for `user` table.

Make a `admin` table as `users` table for simplicity.

**Controller For Admin**
`app/Http/Controllers/AdminAuth/AuthController`
`app/Http/Controllers/AdminAuth/PasswordController`
(note: I just copied these files from `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController` here)

**`config/auth.php`**

```
//Authenticating guards
'guards' => [
    'user' =>[
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'user',
    ],
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admin',
    ],
],  

//User Providers
'providers' => [
    'user' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ]
],  

//Resetting Password  
'passwords' => [
    'clients' => [
        'provider' => 'client',
        'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
    'admins' => [
        'provider' => 'admin',
        'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
],
```

**`route.php`**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    //Login Routes...
    Route::get('/admin/login','AdminAuth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
    Route::post('/admin/login','AdminAuth\AuthController@login');
    Route::get('/admin/logout','AdminAuth\AuthController@logout');

    // Registration Routes...
    Route::get('admin/register', 'AdminAuth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm');
    Route::post('admin/register', 'AdminAuth\AuthController@register');

    Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index');

});
```

**`AdminAuth/AuthController.php`**

Add two methods and specify `$redirectTo` and `$guard`

```
protected $redirectTo = '/admin';
protected $guard = 'admin';
public function showLoginForm()
{
    if (view()->exists('auth.authenticate')) {
        return view('auth.authenticate');
    }

    return view('admin.auth.login');
}
public function showRegistrationForm()
{
    return view('admin.auth.register');
}
```

it will help you to open another login form for admin

**creating a middleware for `admin`**

```
class RedirectIfNotAdmin
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @param  string|null  $guard
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = 'admin')
{
    if (!Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

}

register middleware in `kernel.php`

```
 protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfNotAdmin::class,
];
```

use this middleware in `AdminController`
e.g.,

middleware('admin');
       }
    public function index(){
            return view('admin.dashboard');
        }
    }


That's all needed to make it working and also to get json of authenticated admin use  
 `Auth::guard('admin')->user()`  

**Edit - 1**  
We can access authenticated user directly using  
`Auth::user()`
but if you have two authentication table then you have to use  

    Auth::guard('guard_name')->user()  

for logout  

    Auth::guard('guard_name')->user()->logout()

for authenticated user json  

    Auth::guard('guard_name')->user()  

##Edit 2
Now you can download Laravel 5.2 Multiauth implemented Project http://imrealashu.in/code/laravel/multi-auth-with-laravel-5-2-2/

Comment: thanks a lot man, this was what i was searching for, it worked with a litle bit of modification. thanks a lot +1 for Q and +1 for Ans, wish i could +1 more. thanks a lot..

Comment: @imrealashu, As I have created project as per your answer. But it generates error of multiple classes with same name. So what about that? If I changes class name for admin auth, then where I need to do changes?

Comment: I'd recommend you to separate two auth controllers with different folder. e.g., `Admin\AuthController.php` and `Users\AuthController.php` or you can keep default `Auth\AuthController.php` intact. and make sure to change the `namespace` accordingly.

Comment: @imrealashu, as I have changed namespace for AdminAuth/AuthController, problem is solved. But I have username for admin and email for user. So what changes need to apply for authentication while login admin? And even I can't get login.

Comment: can you please also explain how to "Reset Password" for admin guard.

Comment: yeas sure, give me some time. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent explanation was very useful to me everything.

To use the middleware guest, change the RedirectIfAuthenticated.php file the following line:

Original:

         `if (Auth :: guard ($ guard) -> check ()) { return redirect ('/'); }`

After the change:

       `if (Auth :: guard ('yourcustomguard') -> check () || Auth :: check ()) { return redirect ('/'); }`

Comment: I am trying to make login for admin and user. It works for me with admin but it fails when I try to login user. Any idea why?

Comment: @Aryan will you be able to share some of your code ?

Comment: @CristianMeza Glad I could help and appreciate you for noticing me this one you have mentioned above. I will update my answer.

Comment: @imrealashu Using multi auth is it possible to login both admin and user in different tab in same bowser?

Comment: @KirenSiva yeah, it is possible. I have faced some problem in local server like when user tries to log in and if admin is already logged in then admin gets logged out automatically. But when deployed on live server it works fine.

Comment: Hello again friends, I have been presented a problem.
The problem is that the routes Auth default user are visible although this log with the admin. 
Example: I'm logged in as administrator with the route admins/login, but even I can see the path /login of the default user of Laravel and vice versa. 
Then as I can protect the routes are a user or another when any this log?. Greetings from Chile

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But could you please tell me how should I write the  `Admin/AuthController@register` function? Thanks!

Comment: I am just wondering, why did have to spend so much time doing this. Laravel is supposed to be so easy ... [wink, wink]

Comment: @Jeffz its just because of bad documentation and no working examples on multi-auth.. we expect good documentation and yeah the new cool features on this 5.3 update.

Comment: Can also confirm that this works beautifully on Laravel 5.3! Thanks for the fantastic guide mate.This is probably the only bit of the Laravel documentation that's lacking, and oddly enough if you require it, it's probably one of the most important parts of the entire application

Comment: Hello I have done Multi Auth same way as describe above but every time when I try to login using admin/login after login it redirect to front end side login page say /login not in admin/dashboard please help for same

Comment: did you see [this](http://imrealashu.in/code/laravel/multi-auth-with-laravel-5-2-2/#comment-2978994019) post ? I've also included a multi auth implemented repo [link](https://github.com/imrealashu/laravel-multiauth) there.

Comment: I have one question, does it allow to login two different type of users on same browser but on different tabs. i.e in one browser tab simple user is logged in and in another tab admin user. Is it possible?

Comment: @imrealashu, I have followed all step as per you but logout is not working because Guard was not updated it hold default value. Please tell me

Comment: I made this setup and this works perfectly fine for me but what I want to ask is that how can stop the auto login right after sign up, as I'm putting the register user option inside the Admin and when I as an Admin register some user it makes that user logged in as well then Admin becomes logged in inside the user. So, I think by changing this feature of auto login my problem will be solved, please suggest how to fix this.

Comment: @VikasMeena For that you need to override `register` method of `RegisterUser` trait. Because in register method it logs in user once they complete registration.

Comment: @imrealashu, it is possible to use `user` table for both `admin` and `users`?

Comment: i tried with `'providers' => [
        'users' => [           
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'user',           
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        'admins' => [           
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'user', 
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ]
    ],`. But user login not working

Answer (score 2):

In case this helps anyone, and this may just be due to my lack of understanding of middleware, here's what I had to do to get this working (in addition to the steps taken by @imrealashu)...

In **`route.php`**:

```
Route::get('/admin', [
  'middleware' => 'admin',
  'uses' => 'AdminController@index'
]);
```

This is in the `web` middleware group. Before this I tried putting it in a separate `admin` middleware group and even in an `auth:admin` group but this didn't work, it only worked for me when I specified the middleware as admin on the route itself. I have no idea why this is but I hope it saves others from pulling their hair out like I did.

Comment: I downloaded your multi auth zip file replaced with ezisting project files then when I migrate my DB this error show..[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]  
  Not enough arguments (missing: "name").

Comment: Actually for me admin is logging in but not redirected to admin. After doing this it works can you please tell why's so? I got to register other routes as is it possible with `Route::group(['middleware' => ['admin']], function () {
   //Admin Routes...
});` cause it's not working for me

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy in laravel 5.6. Just go to `config/auth.php` and add this line in `providers` array:

```
'admins' => [
   'driver' => 'database',
   'table' => 'admin_table'
]
```

*Note that we used `database` for driver not `eloquent`.*

Now add this to `guards` array:

```
'admin_guard' => [
   'driver' => 'session',
   'provider' => 'admins'
]
```

Now we're done! Use this when working with admins table:

```
Auth::guard('admin_guard')->User();
```

Cheers.