# Laravel 5.2: How to use auth in middleware

Tags: php, authentication, middleware, laravel-5

I've create a new middleware name Adminpanel

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Adminpanel
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::user()->role == 'admin'){
            return $next($request);
        }else{
            return redirect('admin/login');
        }
    }
}
```

and register middle ware

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'adminpanel' => \App\Http\Middleware\Adminpanel::class,
];
```

and route

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web','adminpanel']], function () {
Route::get('/admin/dashboard/', 'admin\Dashboard@index');
//
```

});

but when I run, It ask me Trying to get property of non-object, means I could not access Auth class here, can somebody tell me what is the mistake and how to access Auth Facade in middleware.

and this is my authentication code

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->input('email'), 'password' => $request->input('password'), 'role' => 'admin'], $request->input('remember'))) 
    {
        return redirect()->intended('admin/dashboard');
    }
    else{
        return redirect('admin')->with('response',-1);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Just see here. I've done what you need.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614753/can-anyone-explain-laravel-5-2-multi-auth-with-example

Comment: I am using single database table and role field for different type of users

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't mean you couldn't access **Auth** class. It means, that user is not authenticated and **Auth::user()** returns **NULL**.

Make sure that only authenticated users can access your route by using **auth** middleware for that route or first check if user is authenticated:

```
if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role == 'admin'){
  return $next($request);
} else {
  return redirect('admin/login');
}
```

Comment: What does it change? Is this the part of your code that is causing the error?

Comment: No, the authenticate function successfully authenticate user and redirect to dashboard page but auth in middleware is working as I mention above.

Comment: The fix above should fix the error, but if your authentication doesn't work properly it will redirect you back to login page - could you confirm that it works like that with above code? If so, we'll get to fixing your authentication

Comment: What is the primary key for your user model?

Comment: you are right, authentication is not working, my users table primary key is id and manual authenticate method is describe above. ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication

Comment: I've done, actually my CSRF Token was not working. Thanks