# Laravel 5.2 Multi Table Authentication ErrorException in AuthManager.php

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I use Laravel 5.2 and I need to use multi table authentication. I read from this link [Can anyone explain Laravel 5.2 Multi Auth with example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614753/can-anyone-explain-laravel-5-2-multi-auth-with-example#answer-34783443)

I modified config/auth.php

```
'guards' => [
    'user' =>[
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'user',
    ],
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admin',
    ],
],  

//User Providers
'providers' => [
    'user' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ]
],  

//Resetting Password  
'passwords' => [
    'user' => [
        'provider' => 'user',
        'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
    'admin' => [
        'provider' => 'admin',
        'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
],
```

Here is part of the controller for login (post method)

```
$admindata = array(
    'email'     => Input::get('email'),
    'password'  => Input::get('password')
);

if (Auth::attempt($admindata)) {
    echo 'SUCCESS!';
} else {
    $admin = Auth::admin();
    return Redirect::to('/b');
}
```

But I got this error

> ErrorException in AuthManager.php line 288: call_user_func_array()
>   expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class
>   'Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard' does not have a method 'admin'

It looks like the error is on `Auth::attempt()`. How to solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the error is not in `attempt` method but here:

```
 $admin = Auth::admin();
```

You try to run here `admin` method and obviously there is no such method in `Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard` class.