# How to Use two Laravel Default Guard?

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

I'm trying to login an Admin and a User with the same form, but the config/auth I just only can to set a one default

This is my **config/auth**

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web_users',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],
'guards' => [
    'web_users' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'web_admins' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ],
],
```

When I log in a User with the default "web_users" I can retrieve his data with the method Auth::user(), but if I log in a Admin with the default "web_admins" can't retrieve anything.

**Routes:**

```
Route::resource('log','LogController');
Route::get('logout','LogController@logout');
```

**Log Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    if(Auth::guard('web_users')->attempt(['email'=>$request['email'],'password'=>$request['password']])) {
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }

    if(Auth::guard('web_admins')->attempt(['email'=>$request['email'],'password'=>$request['password']])) {
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }
}

public function logout()
{
    Auth::logout();
    return Redirect::to('log');
}
```

**Note**: sorry for my english, I don't speak it very well

Comment: [This is very detailed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614753/can-anyone-explain-laravel-5-2-multi-auth-with-example?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

try this for Routes file

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:web_users,web_admin'], function () {  
  Route::resource('log','LogController');
  Route::get('logout','LogController@logout');
});
```