# How to add a register function for multi auth in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

This is a extension of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614753/can-anyone-explain-laravel-5-2-multi-auth-with-example). I am trying to follow the accepted answer for multi auth, adding one more user table `admin` to my Laravel project. I have done all thing as he said, adding the guards, controller, middleware and routes for `admin model`. But when I enter the `locolhost/admin/register`, which is set previously in `routes.php`, and enter the information for registration, I got an error of `View [admin.auth.register] not found.` Given the `routes.php` according to that questions:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
#Route::auth();
Route::get('web-login', 'Auth\AuthController@webLogin');
Route::post('web-login', ['as'=>'web-login','uses'=>'Auth\AuthController@webLoginPost']);

Route::get('/admin/login','AdminAuth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
Route::post('/admin/login','AdminAuth\AuthController@login');
Route::get('/admin/logout','AdminAuth\AuthController@logout');

// Registration Routes...
Route::get('admin/register', 'AdminAuth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm');
Route::post('admin/register', 'AdminAuth\AuthController@register');

Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index');
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});
```

And the `AdminAuth/AuthController.php`:

```
   public function showLoginForm()
{
    if (view()->exists('auth.authenticate')) {
        return view('auth.authenticate');
    }

    return view('admin.auth.login');
}
public function showRegistrationForm()
{
    return view('admin.register');
}
```

Just `showLoginForm` is defined, but the `register` function has not. Do you know how should I define it? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Here is what I have tried:

```
    public function register(Request $request)
{
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }

    Auth::login($this->create($request->all()));

    return redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

But I got an `NotFoundHttpException` error. Do you have any idea of it? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

The error says that you don't have a table called "admins". Make sure you do have it or change the table value to a correct one in your model.

Limit 1 is added to SQL because the auth system is trying to load a single admin (user) record, not a collection.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But there is indeed a `Admin.php` file and the corresponding migration file. When I input `php artisan migrate`. The output is nothing to migrate. How can I check more? Thanks!

Comment: Can you connect to database using any SQL tool and see if the table admins exists? I use MySQL workbench but it can be any other - navicat, sqlyog, phpmyadmin etc

Comment: Which can used in homestead?

Comment: are you familiar with mysql? You can use inline mysql but that's slightly trickier. Basically any tool I mentioned can connect to mysql in homestead too

Comment: It really doesn't exist. But why? I have done the migration already.

Comment: look into migrations table, see if it's there. Also check your laravel error log

Comment: I remigrate and it works this time. But when I register a new ac. No admin is created and I am redirected to the previous page. Do you have any idea?

Comment: There can be quite many reasons. You'll have to debug it yourself. Pay attention to Guards and (controller) properties.

Comment: Seems that the reason is in the `routes.php`: `The reason behind it is because Route::get('/') isn’t under middleware group web if you inspect in routes.php file. Move it under web middleware group and it will work.` But seems now laravel change it to `Route::auth();` simply. Do you know how to deal with this case? Thanks!

Comment: I believe you might wanna have a look at app/Http/Kernel.php. You can assign global middleware (applied to any request), per group or set it separately (via routes or controller). If middleware is the case you can set it the way auth needs it to be

Comment: Now I think I can narrow down my question and I rewrote it. Could you please take a look at it?