# Multi Auth for Laravel 5.2

Tags: php

I'm new in StackOverflow and in laravel and I hope someone can help me to make multi auth in laravel 5.2.

Comment: This link may help: [Laravel 5.2 Multi Auth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614753/can-anyone-explain-laravel-5-2-multi-auth-with-example?s=7%7C2.8639)