# Laravel- Multiauth is not working in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

I am trying to implement multi authentication in `laravel 5.2`. I am following [this article](http://saravanan.tomrain.com/multiauth-in-laravel-5-0/)

My **Auth.php**

```
<?php

return [
 'multi' => array(
   'user' => array(
     'driver' => 'eloquent',
     'model' => 'App\User',
     'table' => 'users',
   ),
   'admin' => array(
     'driver' => 'database',
     'model' => 'App\Admin',
     'table' => 'tbl_admin_user',
   )
 ),
 'password' => [
 'email' => 'emails.password',
 'table' => 'password_resets',
 'expire' => 60,
 ],
];
```

My **App.php**

```
'providers' => [

        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
        //Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        Ollieread\Multiauth\MultiauthServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,

        /*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Class Aliases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This array of class aliases will be registered when this application
    | is started. However, feel free to register as many as you wish as
    | the aliases are "lazy" loaded so they don't hinder performance.
    |
    */

    'aliases' => [

        'App' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
        'Artisan' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
        'Auth' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
        'Blade' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
        'Cache' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
        'Config' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
        'Cookie' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class,
        'Crypt' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
        'DB' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
        'Eloquent' => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
        'Event' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class,
        'File' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,
        'Gate' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::class,
        'Hash' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
        'Lang' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class,
        'Log' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
        'Mail' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
        'Password' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class,
        'Queue' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class,
        'Redirect' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class,
        'Redis' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
        'Request' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
        'Response' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
        'Route' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
        'Schema' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
        'Session' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,
        'Storage' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
        'URL' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
        'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
        'View' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,

    ],

];
```

When I ran the project, I saw the error

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::bindShared()
>   in MultiauthServiceProvider.php line 13

I changed the `MultiAuthServiceProvider.php` to

```
$this->app->singleton('auth', function ($app) {
        $app['auth.loaded'] = true;

        return new \Ollieread\Multiauth\MultiManager($app);
    });
```

and now I am seeing this error as attached in the screenshot
[image]
I am not sure what is trying to instantiate the `Gate Facade`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a custom multi auth like that, I recommend you to use Laravel custom auth `guard` and auth `provider`. Honestly the second method is not tested yet but I think it should be worked.

**1. One model multiple guard**

On your `config/auth.php` add a new guard:

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    // new guard for admin using the same model and table.
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

Then group your routes using `auth:admin`, of course you also have to create another middleware that can check whether current user is an admin user. To get authenticated user instance you need to specify the custom guard: `Auth::guard('admin')->user()`.

To make sure it's worked, create two routes group one with `auth` middleware and one with `auth:admin` middleware, when you have logged in user on routes that uses `auth:admin` try to access the other routes group you should be asked to login again.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return 'You are logged in using guard: web';
    });
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:admin'], function () {
    Route::get('/admin', function () {
        return 'You are logged in using guard: admin';
    });
});
```

**2. Multiple models**

Again on your `config/auth.php`, create new custom provider:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    'admins' => [
         'driver' => 'eloquent',
         'model' => App\Admin::class',
     ],
],
```

Then create a custom guard with `admins` as provider:

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    // new guard for admin using custom provider.
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
],
```

Using this method you don't need to create custom middleware, use `auth:admin` should be fine.

Comment: I tried the `Laravel` way as explained in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614753/can-anyone-explain-laravel-5-2-multi-auth-with-example but it register's me only in users table

Comment: Do you mean when you register `Admin` user it goes to `users` table? if so then you must be still use `User` model on `create()` method of `AuthController`.

Comment: Also on your `AuthController` for admin auth you must specify the custom guard by adding this property `protected $guard = 'admin';`