# Multi auth for laravel 5.2 use middleware

Tags: php, laravel

I want to use multi authenticate in `Laravel 5.2`. But I found a strange problem.

Here is my code in `route.php`.

However I can not get `$errors` in the `login.blade.php`, it just returns `null`.

```
<?php 
  Route::group(['middleware' => ['web'], 'namespace' => 'Admin', 'prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
  Route::auth();
});
?>
```

But when I remove the web middleware, it works.

```
<?php 
  Route::group(`enter code here`['namespace' => 'Admin', 'prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
  Route::auth();
});
?>
```

I don't know why. My understanding is that when I want to use the session, I must use the web middleware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because on Laravel 5.2 the `web` middleware is automatically applied, your routes in `routes.php` are grouped with prefix `App\Http\Controllers` and `web` middleware. You can find this definition on `mapWebRoutes()` method of the `RouteServiceProdiver.php`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was great !  By the way,Is there any way can load different providers? For example,in frontend,just load A,B providers. but in backend,  load C,D providers?                                                                                                    Really appreciate you

Comment: By saying provider does it mean auth providers? or service providers. I'm guessing that you want to apply different auth guard for backend and frontend.

Comment: Sorry for my unclear expression.I mean the app.php in config folder. 'providers' =>[....]     I want to use the laravel generotor and some other packages in backend. but these need not to load in frontend.

Comment: I'm not sure there is such way. Why would you do that anyway? If you simply want to change the definition of `web` middleware then you only need to change/remove it from your `RouteServiceProvider.php`. If you want to apply multiple auth guards and providers then you can read my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37560662/2127007

Comment: I may think  too much packages load will affect the speed of my web.I found an article,it said how to load different services providers for  local or development environment. Here is the link [link](https://www.damchey.com/2015/06/load-service-providers-aliases-for-localdevelopment-environment-only-in-laravel-5/)       It does not matter for me. Thank you for your answer~ o(∩_∩)o