# Authentication user provider is not defined in laravel

Tags: authentication, laravel-5

Based on this [Can anyone explain Laravel 5.2 Multi Auth with example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614753/can-anyone-explain-laravel-5-2-multi-auth-with-example)

i will like to implement custom authentication on my app for the admin and users section but the whole concept is confusing maybe it is new to me in laravel 5.2 (my version) but at this stage i can say if i am getting it right or wrong but this is the error that is displaying.

```
InvalidArgumentException in CreatesUserProviders.php line 40:
Authentication user provider [] is not defined.
```

so i have done what @imrealashu answered but still i have issues.

Answer (score 0):

It means that you didn't pass the guard like this:

```
auth('admin')->user();
//or
Auth::guard('admin')->user();
```

Or when you call the middleware auth in your controller, you need to pass the guard:

```
$this->middleware('auth:admin');
```

This video explains it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vxh2ikaydfo (In spanish but its understandable  )

Answer (score 0):

I got that error when I tried to change in `auth.php`:

```
'provider' => 'users'
```

to

```
'provider' => 'user'
```

because my database table was `user`, not `users`.

That's not necessary. I just had to add to the `User` Eloquent class:

```
protected $table = 'user';
```