# Laravel 5.2 make:auth middleware does not work for $guard

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I looking at Laravel 5.2 and the easy to use "make:auth" and the multi-auth.

I think there is a bug because in the generated middleware `"App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate"` at `handle()` method call the $guard parameter is always null.
So Laravel use `"default"=>"gard"=>"xyz` defined in "`auth.php`", not the one defined by the $guard property in `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController`.

Actually i am trying to redirect website user to home controller and website admin to admin controller after login.

Help me come out from this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can anyone explain Laravel 5.2 Multi Auth with example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614753/can-anyone-explain-laravel-5-2-multi-auth-with-example)

Comment: You should look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614753/can-anyone-explain-laravel-5-2-multi-auth-with-example) for answer