# Laravel 5.3: Create Admin Middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I created a Middleware called Admin

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        if (Auth::user()->isAdmin())
            return redirect('/list_host');
        else {
            // return $next($request);
            return redirect('/home');
        }
    }
}
```

IsAdmin looks like this:

```
public function isAdmin()
{
    return $this->is_admin;
}
```

And their I want to check if the user is logged in and has admin-rights. 
I also added it to Kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth'       => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings'   => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'can'        => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest'      => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle'   => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'admin'      => \App\Http\Auth\Middleware\Admin::class,
];
```

And then I use it in the Routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/list_hosts', function () {
    return view('/list_hosts');
})->middleware('admin');
```

Unfortunately also none Admins can view the Site. Any suggestions?

Comment: How does the system know if a user has admin rights?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614753/can-anyone-explain-laravel-5-2-multi-auth-with-example

Comment: aren't you by chance falling into an infinite loop with the redirects? The middleware redirects admin to itself for ever, no?

Comment: Yeah you are right. I adapted the Code like Zoltán Jére said, but it redirects me even tough I login as a non Admin-user. Anyone know why

Comment: is_admin is a boolean in the DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your Middleware should return something in every case. In your example when your first if failes there is no return anymore.

The second problem is that your Middleware redirects to route `/list_hosts` which cause an infinite loop to itself.

Try to use this

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    return Auth::user()->isAdmin() ? $next($request) : redirect('/home');
}
```

Off: However I highly reccomend using brackets after every if statetement, even when you have only one line inside.

Comment: Thanks solved it. I had stupidly another Route with auth-Middleware so it didn't use mine. :D