# How can I change Laravel default authentication user table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

How can I change Laravel default authentication user table  to my table. After that forget password reset, reset mail should work perfectly

My table structure like

username (email),
password,
lastlogin,
remember_token,
role_id

Comment: You need to change Model in auth.php

Comment: go through "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614753/can-anyone-explain-laravel-5-2-multi-auth-with-example" link

Comment: login & register working. but after login i want set last login date. forget password & reset not working.

Comment: Thanks Akshay Deshmukh & Nikhil Radadiya

Answer (score 1):

As Per [Laravel Discussion Thread](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/change-default-users-table-for-authentication) :

> Have a look at the file `config/auth.php`. You'll find the name of the
>   table in there:
>
> ```
> 'table' => 'users',
> ```

Comment: @SusantaKumarDas, if you have find your answer, you can post correct answer and accept it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

change your `User.php` model adding `protected $table = 'your_table_name'` even with `protected $primaryKey = 'user_id'` if needed

Comment: you should implement your own forget/reset password

Answer (score 0):

Change the table information in `config/auth.php`.

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],
```

As for changing the `email` field to `username`, the built in auth would break. You need to make changes to almost all the default auth controllers in `app/Http/Controllers/Auth`. You may need to extend some methods to override them to use `username`. For instance `RegisterController` is simple. You just need to edit the validator and create methods. Where as the other controllers use traits which you need to explore to extract the methods that has to be changed to make the `username` field work.

Comment: login & register working. but after login i want set last login date. forget password & reset not working

Comment: @you need to make the appropriate changes in the controller then. You can't expect people to do all the work for you. At least make an effort.