# Multi auth using one table Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, authentication

I want to use the multi authentication Laravel but with only one table "users"

How can I implement this?

Comment: If you asking about separate dashboard for user and admin, then you may add new column as type in user table

Comment: The need for my project is like this, because I have backoffice for admins, but now I want to implement a small backoffice for the simple users, and this small backoffice is totally different than the admins

Comment: @FairyDancer i want to implement a small backoffice for simple users only

Comment: is the menu are same for both users?

Comment: The menu is different,
My project is an online donation site, I want to create a small space for the site users so that they can consult their donations and their profile and they can comment for each cause

Comment: I recommend using 2 separate drivers for each authentication model. While this takes a bit more to implement, it ensures code reusability and extensibility.

Answer (score 4):

Separate drivers and models for each type of user that requires authentication is the correct way to go. You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614753/can-anyone-explain-laravel-5-2-multi-auth-with-example) thread, and learn more about it. With that being said, if you want something quick but not so secure and extensible, you could do the following:

You could have a flag in your Users migration that determines the type of user like so:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_type');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

For this example, we will have a regular user as a type 1 and an Admin as a type 2.

Then, you could create a middleware that checks if the user has the required `'user_type'` flag every single time your regular user programming logic differs to that of the admin. You could also check upon the instantiation of a specific `Controller`.

In this example, we'll create two middleware, one for the regular user, and another for the admin. This will protect the same `User` driver/model with different user type accessing each other resources, again, by using the attribute `user_type` we defined in the migration.

Creating the two middleware:

`php artisan make:middleware UserMiddleware`

and

`php artisan make:middleware AdminMiddleware`

We register them in our `Kernel.php`. It should look like this:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'user' => \App\Http\Middleware\UserMiddleware::class,
        'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class
    ];
```

Once we have registered our middleware in our Kernel, we modify their `handle()` method to suit our needs:

`UserMiddleware.php`:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::user()->user_type == 1)
            return $next($request);
        return redirect('/');
    }
```

`AdminMiddleware.php`:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::user()->user_type == 2)
            return $next($request);
        return redirect('/');
    }
```

The `Auth::user()` Facade will return an instance of your logged in user in both cases, which then we check if it is a 1 or a 2. If they match their corresponding values, we proceed to wherever we are intended to go, else, we can redirect to somewhere else in your app, say, the home route `/`.

After this, we can proceed to protect routes or controllers with our brand new middleware.

For example, if you wanted to make a route only available to admins, but not to regular users, you could do:

`routes/web.php`:

```
Route::get('/admin', function () {
    return view('admin');
})->middleware('admin');
```

Then that specific route, will be protected to those `User`s that are created with the attribute `user_type` set to 2.

I hope this helps you a little bit.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you @JackGal , i will try this logic ^^

Comment: @YassineMabrouk No worries. I added a reference to my answer in case you might want to explore the multiple auth drivers. I hope my answer is able to help you!

Comment: ,I tried your logic unfortunately, I could not solve my need :(

Comment: By using this method, can we open both admin and normal user pages in a single browser window? also if we logout or logged in from admin then it should not affect the normal user Auth and vise versa.