# Laravel 5.4 Multiple Authentication is is not working propoerly

Tags: laravel

I am using Multiple Authentication in laravel 5.4. Here I have two controller for login. One is for normal user and other is for admin. Both controller is restricted by guest middleware. Because of using this guest controller is if a person is logged in as admin or user he must not to get any log in page.  But this guest middleware only work when I log in using UserController. I mean if I log in using user controller then try to go to the log in page or admin page it redirect me to user dashboard page. That is ok. But when I log in using AdminLoginController then try to log in as user or log in again as admin it allow me to log in again. 
I have used this construct function in both controller.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');

}
```

Help me please.

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614753/can-anyone-explain-laravel-5-2-multi-auth-with-example) can't solved my problem. Because I have downloaded code from that solution and I still got this error. That logged in admin can visit user log in form. This error also have in this answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can anyone explain Laravel 5.2 Multi Auth with example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614753/can-anyone-explain-laravel-5-2-multi-auth-with-example)

Comment: My problem is difference.  I have done everything nicely. And everything is working fine. Just `guest` 'middleware is not working for `AdminLoginController`. I just want to know how I can make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Restrict them with the auth middleware:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');

}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#protecting-routes