# Two different models for authentication in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

Suppose I have two different models and tables named `user` and `company`.

As you know laravel uses `User` model to manage Authentication. but beacause I have two different model I want can manage them separately.

I'm using laravel 5.4 and I do not know how can do that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are talking about multiple authentication system, then you have to create multiple **guards** to achieve that.

There is nice answer to the same question.

[Can anyone explain Laravel 5.2 Multi Auth with example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614753/can-anyone-explain-laravel-5-2-multi-auth-with-example)

It's on Laravel 5.2, but it can be easily implemented on Laravel 5.4.

1. Create a model **App\Company** which extends **Authenticatable Class**. This model will work as user model which will **company** guard (in the next step)

   ```
   namespace App;

   use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
   use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

   class Company extends Authenticatable
   {

       use Notifiable;

       /**
        * The attributes that are mass assignable.
        *
        * @var array
        */
       protected $fillable = [
           'name', 'email', 'password',
       ];

       /**
        * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
        *
        * @var array
        */
       protected $hidden = [
           'password', 'remember_token',
       ];

   }
   ```
2. Create an guard and a provider for model **App\Company**.

   ```
   // Authenticating guards and providers

   'guards' => [
       'web' => [
           'driver' => 'session',
           'provider' => 'users',
       ],
       'api' => [
           'driver' => 'token',
           'provider' => 'users',
       ],
       'company' => [
           'driver' => 'session',
           'provider' => 'company',
       ],
   ],

   // Providers 

   'providers' => [
       'users' => [
           'driver' => 'eloquent',
           'model' => App\User::class,
       ],
       'company' => [
           'driver' => 'eloquent',
           'model' => App\Company::class,
       ]
   ],
   ```

Now you can find user according to the different guards.

```
$user = Auth::guard('company')->user();
// Or...
$user = auth()->guard('company')->user();
dd($user);
```

3. Now create Auth controller for Company **App\Http\Controllers\Auth\CompanyLoginController** same as **Auth\LoginController**.
   Specify **$redirectTo** and **guard**

   ```
   //Auth\ComapnyLoginController.php

   protected $redirectTo = '/comapany';
   protected $guard = 'comapany';

   public function showLoginForm()
   {
       if (view()->exists('auth.authenticate')) {
           return view('auth.authenticate');
       }

       return view('comapany.auth.login');
   }
   ```

now create login form for user - company.auth.login view same as user's login form.

4. Now create routes

   ```
   //Login Routes...
   Route::group(['prefix'=>'company', 'middleware'=>'company'], function(){
       Route::get('/login','Auth\CompanyLoginController@showLoginForm');
       Route::post('/login','Auth\CompanyLoginController@login');
       // ...
       // rest of the company dashboard and other links
       // ...
       Route::get('/logout','Auth\CompanyLoginController@logout');
   });
   ```
5. Create a middleware for company

   ```
   class RedirectIfNotCompany
   {
       /**
        * Handle an incoming request.
        *
        * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
        * @param  \Closure  $next
        * @param  string|null  $guard
        * @return mixed
        */
       public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = 'company')
       {
           if (!Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
               return redirect('/');
           }

           return $next($request);
       }
   }
   ```

   and register it to kernal.php

   ```
   protected $routeMiddleware = [
       'company' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfNotCompany::class,
   ];
   ```

And thats all you need.
Access user by the name of guard

```
Auth::guard('company')->user()
```

Comment: if you know how can I do exactly in laravel 5.4 please guide me. solution that described in suggested link is long and have many configurations.

Comment: I wanted to but its the exact same answer. It will be same as long as in given answer. I will try to explain it in short steps but, here are some tutorials links https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iKRLrJXNN4M  and http://www.expertphp.in/article/how-to-implement-multi-auth-in-laravel-5-4-with-example

Comment: Updated answer with necessary steps. And yeah that is also a long answer. lol

Comment: @abid-reza, what about if I want to access logged-in user via `Auth::user()`? in this case I must in many situations check `Auth::user()` for normal user or `Auth::guard('company')->user()` for company user , right?

Comment: Yes exactly. Everything else is same.

Comment: is not any other way where using `Auth::user()` detect and return real user ?

Comment: Auth::user() will always give the current logged in user.

Comment: But in this case when I try `Auth::user()` it returns `null` while a company user is logged-in.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I checked, in config/auth.php you can see in defaults  array, gaurd => 'web' is there. So you have to use Auth::guard('company')->user() to get company user.