# How to reference a specific model for a controller laravel

Tags: php, laravel, rest, authentication

I am currently trying to use my Business model (`Business.php`) to login business users. For some reason it is using my Consumer model (`Consumer.php`)

How can I reference my Business model in my `BusinessAuthController.php`?

**BusinessAuthController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Business;


class businessAuthController extends Controller
{
    public function login()
    {
        $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);

        if (! $token = auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
           return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }

        return $this->respondWithToken($token);
   }
}
```

**Business.php**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Business extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject//Model
{
    use Notifiable;
    protected $table = 'businesses';
    protected $primaryKey = 'bus_id';

    protected $fillable = [ 'bus_id', 'bus_name', 'bus_address', 'bus_city', 'bus_prov', 'bus_postal', 'bus_phone', 'email', 'password', 'cashback_percent', 'bus_cover_photo', 'bus_profile_pic'];

    protected $hidden = [
       'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
    * Return a key value array, containing any custom claims to be added to the JWT.
    *
    * @return array
    */
    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

I don't see where it is referencing the Consumer Model here but need it to reference the Business Model.

Comment: Open User.php Model and then you can mention 
protected $table = 'my_flights';
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#defining-models

Comment: just for reference `User.php` is now `Consumer.php` Can I create `Business.php` and reference that in the controller? I dont see it referencing it in the current `AuthController.php`

Comment: Go through the basic documentation, you will come to know that you need to define model for every table to interact easily with the database. Than in your controller you can easily use the model.

Comment: @Jay you need to extends  Authenticatable

Comment: Ya you can create `Business.php` and reference that in controller. post your `Consumer.php` in the question.

Comment: @DsRaj do I need to do that in my `AuthController.php`?

Comment: See here `protected $table = 'consumers';` your consumer table is called.

Comment: @parthu_panther Yes, Thank you. I now understand that but what Im trying to do now is use my Business model (`Business.php`). Which is similar to the `Consumer.php` (just with different values), in my `BusinessAuthController.php`. currently when I run my query it still pulls from the consumers table. (ill add my `BusinessAuthController.php` to the question.

Comment: I reframed my question to make more sense now that I had a bit of a better understanding.

Comment: I would suggest you go through this article. you need to know how it works rather than to simply change the file name.  https://hackernoon.com/laravel-multiple-authentication-80daa855322b

Comment: @parthu_panther Im kind of confused in what you mean by going through the article and learn how it works. Is my problem lying in middleware? That was the only thing it did different from what I did.

Comment: You said that after you run your query it still pulls from the consumers table. So middleware is the thing which is lacking. Yes it will let your system know when to fork result of query from consumers table and when to fork results of query from business table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two different models for authentication in laravel 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47124706/two-different-models-for-authentication-in-laravel-5-4)