# how to connect a custom table and a custom model to a auth::attempt of laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, model, customization

I have a table which is named ‘ prj_user ‘ and user data’s are stored in this table

Table’s fields has written below

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `prj_users` (
`usr_user_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`usr_firstname` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`usr_lastname` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`usr_email` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`usr_pass` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`usr_created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`usr_updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`usr_user_id`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

For this table I have created  a Model which is named  UserCustom.php at ‘app/models/ UserCustom.php’And also I have created a folder which is called “Models” and all the projects’ models will be saved on that folder

The following code is the model code of UserCustom.php.

```
namespace App\Models;


use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserCustom extends Model
{
  public $table='prj_users';
  public $primaryKey='usr_user_id';

  const CREATED_AT='usr_created_at';
  const UPDATED_AT='usr_updated_at';

  protected $fillable = [
    'usr_user_id',
    'usr_firstname',
    'usr_lastname',
    'usr_email',
    'usr_pass',
    'usr_lastname',
    'usr_created_at',
    'usr_updated_at',
  ];

}
```

I want to connect auth::attempt  And Other class methods auth to this table and this Model

I don’t  want to use Model User as and table User as laravel’s default.

Can Laravel be customized at this level?

Is it possible at all?

Comment: May be this tutorial will help you : https://scotch.io/@sukelali/how-to-create-multi-table-authentication-in-laravel

Comment: Your answer can be found here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47124706/two-different-models-for-authentication-in-laravel-5-4)

Comment: I had previously read these two articles. But the problem is that I have used ‘usr_email’ and ‘usr_pass’ instead of Email and Password so it is not Laravel default mode any more, and it causes the error.

Comment: @mohsen you can change field name in this file Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers in line 144 change username to usr_email ,You can also find the password field in this file

Answer (score 1):

I add the following codes to file config/auth.php

```
<?php
'guards' => [

'usercustom' => [
    'driver' => 'session',
    'provider' => 'userCustomProvider',
  ],
],

'providers' => [

  'userCustomProvider' => [
    'driver' => 'eloquent',
    'model' => App\Models\UserCustom::class,
  ],

],
?>
```

Then I made two classes CustomAuthProvider And CustomUserProvider in Providers   floder

```
<?php
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

use App\Providers\CustomUserProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class CustomAuthProvider extends ServiceProvider {

  /**
   * Bootstrap the application services.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function boot()
  {
    $this->app['auth']->extend('usercustom',function()
    {
      return new CustomUserProvider();
    });
  }

  /**
   * Register the application services.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function register()
  {
    //
  }
}


<?php

namespace App\Providers;
use App\Models\UserCustom;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Auth\GenericUser;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class CustomUserProvider implements UserProvider {

  /**
   * Retrieve a user by their unique identifier.
   *
   * @param  mixed $identifier
   * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null
   */
  public function retrieveById($identifier)
  {
    // TODO: Implement retrieveById() method.


    $qry = UserCustom::where('usr_user_id','=',$identifier);

    if($qry->count() >0)
    {
      $user = $qry->select('usr_user_id', 'usr_firstname', 'usr_last_name', 'usr_email', 'usr_pass')->first();

      $attributes = array(
        'usr_user_id' => $user->usr_user_id,
        'usr_firstname' => $user->usr_firstname,
        'usr_last_name' => $user->usr_last_name,
        'usr_email' => $user->usr_email,
        'usr_pass' => $user->usr_pass,
      );

      return $user;
    }
    return null;
  }

  /**
   * Retrieve a user by by their unique identifier and "remember me" token.
   *
   * @param  mixed $identifier
   * @param  string $token
   * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null
   */
  public function retrieveByToken($identifier, $token)
  {
    // TODO: Implement retrieveByToken() method.
    $qry = UserCustom::where('usr_user_id','=',$identifier);

    if($qry->count() >0)
    {
      $user = $qry->select('usr_user_id', 'usr_firstname', 'usr_last_name', 'usr_email', 'usr_pass')->first();

      $attributes = array(
        'usr_user_id' => $user->usr_user_id,
        'usr_firstname' => $user->usr_firstname,
        'usr_last_name' => $user->usr_last_name,
        'usr_email' => $user->usr_email,
        'usr_pass' => $user->usr_pass,
      );

      return $user;
    }
    return null;



  }

  /**
   * Update the "remember me" token for the given user in storage.
   *
   * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable $user
   * @param  string $token
   * @return void
   */
  public function updateRememberToken(Authenticatable $user, $token)
  {
    // TODO: Implement updateRememberToken() method.
    $user->setRememberToken($token);

    $user->save();

  }

  /**
   * Retrieve a user by the given credentials.
   *
   * @param  array $credentials
   * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null
   */
  public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
  {

    // TODO: Implement retrieveByCredentials() method.
    $qry = UserCustom::where('usr_email','=',$credentials['usr_email']);

    if($qry->count() > 0)
    {
      $user = $qry->select('usr_user_id','usr_email','usr_pass')->first();


      return $user;
    }

    return null;


  }

  /**
   * Validate a user against the given credentials.
   *
   * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable $user
   * @param  array $credentials
   * @return bool
   */
  public function validateCredentials(Authenticatable $user, array $credentials)
  {
    // TODO: Implement validateCredentials() method.
    // we'll assume if a user was retrieved, it's good

    // DIFFERENT THAN ORIGINAL ANSWER
    if($user->email == $credentials['usr_email'] && Hash::check($credentials['usr_pass'], $user->getAuthPassword()))//$user->getAuthPassword() == md5($credentials['password'].\Config::get('constants.SALT')))
    {


      //$user->last_login_time = Carbon::now();
      $user->save();

      return true;
    }
    return false;


  }
}
```

Then I made  Two Routes

```
Route::get('user/login','UserController@loginForm');
Route::post('user/login','UserController@loginCheck');
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{


    public function loginForm () {
      return view('login');
    }

    public function loginCheck (Request $request) {

      $credentials=array([
        'usr_email'=> $request->email,
        'usr_pass'=>$request->password
      ]);
     if (Auth::guard('usercustom')->attempt($credentials)){
       echo "1";
     }else {
       echo "0";
     }

    }


}
```

I wrote the Class Model in the begging of the Topic
When reached the Auth::guard, the following error has appeared

QLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `tua_users` where `0` in (test@test.com, 123456) limit 1)
Previous exceptions
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where clause' (42S22)

I Search too much on the internet But I can’t Solve the problem.
The Problem is at table’s fields.laravel wants email and password by default while I have changed them to “usr_email” and “usr_pass”.and also I have changed the table and the model

Answer (score 0):

In config\auth.php, 
Create new guard as

```
'customguard' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'userscustom',
    ],
```

and also create the provider as

```
'userscustom' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\UserCustom::class,
    ],
```

and then change the default guard to 'cutomguard'. Remember to make the relevant changes to password as well.

Comment: I have tried this before .It was not enough so we need to make more changes in Laravel.We need to represent the table’s fields in our new laravel Auth especially ‘usr_email’ and ‘usr_pass’

Comment: In your user controller, define $username and $password. E.g: protected $username = 'usr_email'; protected $password = 'usr_pass'; and call attempt() method.