# How Can I dynamicaly change users table name?

Tags: php, laravel

My app has two types of users : teachers and parents. When you log in you have to specify what type you are.

I change the table name in user's constructor function :

```
public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        if(self::$userType === null)
        {

            self::$userType = request('user_type');

              switch(self::$userType)
             {
                 case 'teacher':
                  self::$userType = 'teachers';
                  $this->table = self::$userType;
                 break;

                 default:
                   self::$userType = 'procreators';
                   $this->table = self::$userType;
                 break;

             }
        }
```

This code works. However I decided to change failed authentication behavior in AuthenticatesUsers trait. This is it :

```
$password = bcrypt($request->input('password'));
        $username = $request->input('name');

         if(!User::where('name', 'LIKE', $username)->exists())
         {
             throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                $this->username() => ['User login does not exist'],
             ]);
         }
         else if(!User::where('password', 'LIKE', $password)->exists())
         {
            throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                'password' => ['invalid password'],
             ]); 
         }
```

When I type in wrong password I get an error that says "users" table does not exists. So it means it still uses the old name 'users'. I don't know why. How can I dynamically change the table's name? Apparently this code in constructor method is not enough.

Comment: What's the reasoning to use separate tables? Generally this is done with a `roles` table (`student` and `teacher` role), a `type` column on `users` or a `boolean` for `is_student`, `is_teacher` etc. Dividing your users to separate tables is definitely the most difficult approach considering the way Laravel's auth works.

Comment: Consider this. Teachers and parents are described by different columns. Most of teacher's columns are useless for parents. Most of parent's columns are useles for teacher. So putting them in one table creates reduntand data and is less readable.

Comment: If the columns are different, then they are separate models. Switching a table name will cause more problems than you think.  You likely want to make separate models and then authenticate against either one. This may help you; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47124706/two-different-models-for-authentication-in-laravel-5-4

Comment: Counter-consider; leave the pertinent data in `users` (`email`, `password`, etc), add the relevant columns to a `teachers` and `students` table with a linking `user_id`, or if using `roles`, have the data as `pivot` columns, etc. I agree that you don't want redundant columns, but there's alternative solutions that still keeps the single `users` table intact. (And sorry, I keep reading `students` for some reason; same logic applies to `parents` though)

Comment: You most likely convinced me. If changing table's name is so problematic then your solution seems to be the best one. But I can't understand why changing a table's name is so problematic....

Answer (score 0):

Maybe static instead of self?  If that isn't it, what is  request('user_type') returning?

```
static::$userType = 'teachers';
```

Comment: I tried static. It does not help. request('user_type') returns correct value selected by a user in the select menu.

Comment: I'd add a type column to the user table rather than use two different tables. Otherwise you could try two different models and instantiate the correct class depending on the type of user logging in.

Answer (score 0):

```
Schema::rename('old_table_name', 'teacher');
```