# Laravel: 2 Registration Forms with Login

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm working in Laravel 8 and like to know what's the best approach for logging in with the 2 registration forms I have already set up. The forms are set up with just validation, but trying to figure out how to have a login for these different sign-up roles, which will go to 2 different dashboards.

This is where I'm at with my code...

web.php

```
// Profile
Route::get('/register/profile', [RegisterProfileController::class, 'index'])->name('register_profile');
Route::post('/register/profile', [RegisterProfileController::class, 'store']);

// Business
Route::get('/register/business', [RegisterBusinessController::class, 'index'])->name('register_business');
Route::post('/register/business', [RegisterBusinessController::class, 'store']);
```

RegisterProfileController.php (with just validation)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RegisterIndividualController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('auth.register_profile');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'firstname' => 'required|max:255',
            'lastname' => 'required|max:255',
            'username' => 'required|min:8|max:60|alpha_num',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255',
            'phone' => 'required|digits:10',
            'city' => 'required|max:100',
            'state' => 'required',
            'zip' => 'required|digits:5',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed'
        ]
    }
}
```

RegisterBusinessController.php (with just validation)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RegisterBusinessController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('auth.register_business');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'businessname' => 'required|max:255',
            'firstname' => 'required|max:255',
            'lastname' => 'required|max:255',
            'username' => 'required|min:8|max:60||alpha_num',
            'businessemail' => 'required|email|max:255',
            'phone' => 'required|digits:10',
            'address' => 'required|max:255',
            'city' => 'required|max:100',
            'state' => 'required',
            'zip' => 'required|digits:5',
            'website' => 'required|url',
            'industry' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed'
        ]
    }
}
```

I created the migration schema for each:

2021_10_26_011205_create_individuals_table.php

2021_10_26_011224_create_businesses_table.php

Comment: For making authentication easier, you can use one "users" table where those users are stored. If your goal is to have different roles per authenticated user, you need to take another approach, where you have assigned a role to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use Laravel's built-in authentication system, then you can set up your own [authentication guards](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#adding-custom-guards), which would let you log in using your existing models (here's a [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47124760/8292439) with an example of setting up authentication with multiple models). Once you have this set up, you could then use the relevant guard in your login controller:

```php
// Get the business model
$business = Business::where('businessemail', $request->input('businessemail'))->firstOrFail();

// Verify the password
if (Hash::check($request->input('password'), $business->password)) {
    // Log in
    Auth::guard('business')->login($business);
} else {
    // Incorrect password
}
```

Additionally, since it looks like you're still in the early stages of development, I would recommend reconsidering your authentication model. Instead of having two completely different tables, and needing to set up two different authentication guards, I would recommend using the `User` model for both individuals and businesses, and adding an `account_type` column. You could then create a `business_profiles` table, which links to the `users` table via a `user_id` column, which would hold the business-only information (`businessname`, `industry`, and `website`).

Comment: I took the second approach you mentioned and it worked out perfectly. Thank you!