# Multi Auth with single user table in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to Multi Auth with `single` table in laravel 5.2.

I tried this way. But frontend login working.

Laravel 5.2 has a new `artisan` command.

`php artisan make:auth`

it will generate basic login/register `route`, `view` and `controller` for `user` table.

Make a `admin` table as `users` table for simplicity.

**Controller For Admin**
`app/Http/Controllers/AdminAuth/AuthController`
`app/Http/Controllers/AdminAuth/PasswordController`
(note: I just copied these files from `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController` here)

**`config/auth.php`**

```
//Authenticating guards

return [
'guards' => [
    'user' =>[
    'driver' => 'session',
    'provider' => 'user',
    ],
    'admin' => [
    'driver' => 'session',
    'provider' => 'admin',
    ],
],  

//User Providers
'providers' => [
    'user' => [
    'driver' => 'database',
    'table' => 'user',
    'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'admin' => [
    'driver' => 'database',
    'table' => 'user',
    'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ]
],  

//Resetting Password  
'passwords' => [
    'clients' => [
    'provider' => 'client',
    'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
    'table' => 'password_resets',
    'expire' => 60,
    ],
    'admins' => [
    'provider' => 'admin',
    'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
    'table' => 'password_resets',
    'expire' => 60,
    ],
],
];
```

**`route.php`**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    //Login Routes...
    Route::get('/admin/login','AdminAuth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
    Route::post('/admin/login','AdminAuth\AuthController@login');
    Route::get('/admin/logout','AdminAuth\AuthController@logout');

    // Registration Routes...
    Route::get('admin/register', 'AdminAuth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm');
    Route::post('admin/register', 'AdminAuth\AuthController@register');

    Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index');

});
```

**`AdminAuth/AuthController.php`**

Add two methods and specify `$redirectTo` and `$guard`

```
protected $redirectTo = '/admin';
protected $guard = 'admin';
public function showLoginForm()
{
    if (view()->exists('auth.authenticate')) {
        return view('auth.authenticate');
    }

    return view('admin.auth.login');
}
public function showRegistrationForm()
{
    return view('admin.auth.register');
}
```

it will help you to open another login form for admin

**creating a middleware for `admin`**

```
class RedirectIfNotAdmin
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @param  string|null  $guard
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = 'admin')
{
    if (!Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

}

register middleware in `kernel.php`

```
 protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfNotAdmin::class,
];
```

use this middleware in `AdminController` 
e.g.,

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('admin');
   }
public function index(){
        return view('admin.dashboard');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `AdminAuth/AuthController.php`.

```
   public function guard()
    {
        return auth()->guard('admin');
    }
```

and instead of give table name inside providers put `protected $table = 'users'` in your Admin model.
You can see this for further more details: https://scotch.io/@sukelali/how-to-create-multi-table-authentication-in-laravel

Comment: I want to user single `user` table for multi auth

Comment: I follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614753/can-anyone-explain-laravel-5-2-multi-auth-with-example/34783443

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a guard here, Instead; you can use middleware here. Add a user type column here in user table and then create middleware for that.